# Extra content at the end of the document while parsing XML in R

Tags: r, xml

I run the following to extract data from XML using R

```
library(XML);library(RCurl);
fileUrl <- "https://w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"
doc <- xmlTreeParse(getURL(fileUrl),useInternal=TRUE)
rootNode <- xmlRoot(doc)
```

Error:

```
Extra content at the end of the document
Error: 1: Extra content at the end of the document
```

The XML file has no problems what so ever, it works on the browser and worked a few days before. I am unable to find any help online. Can somebody help me understanding where I could be going wrong or how to test it?

### Background

It worked a few days back. And then I installed package `XLSX' (which was quite some librarys) and then *it appears* that I get the above error. So I removed the whole installation and got back with a fresh installation of R. I have documented the process of uninstalling and re-installing [here](http://agent18.github.io/R-installation.html). I have spent about 10 hours on this issue, but even after a complete reinstallation the same error prevails!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax seems to be wrong. It has nothing to do with the XLSX installation for sure as I have tested it with the right syntax.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
fileURL <- "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"
xData <- getURL(fileURL)
doc <- xmlParse(xData)
rootNode <-xmlRoot(doc)
```

or we could also use this:

```
library (XML)
library(httr)
fileUrl <- "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"
doc <- xmlTreeParse(GET(fileUrl),useInternal=TRUE)
rootNode <- xmlRoot(doc)
```